# How to python-execute-file a django custom command in emacs

Tags: django, emacs

How can I `C-c C-c` or `python-execute-file` a django custom command? Currently I get this error (using the emacs settings at the bottom):

```bash
-*- mode: compilation; default-directory: "~/src/django/" -*-
Comint started at Fri Feb 17 16:45:33

/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-OfUvXXat/bin/python csv_import.py
/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-OfUvXXat/bin/python: can't open file 'csv_import.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Inferior Python exited abnormally with code 2 at Fri Feb 17 16:45:33
```

**This works as expected: `python manage.py csv_import`**

*~/django/crm/management/commands/csv_import.py:*

```py
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from crm.models import Organization,Person
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
       print(Organization.objects.all())
```

I tried to no avail many settings e.g.

```lisp
(setq python-shell-interpreter "python"
      python-shell-interpreter-args "-i /home/user/src/django/manage.py shell")

(defun django-shell ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((python-shell-interpreter (read-file-name "Locate manage.py "))
        (python-shell-interpreter-args "shell"))
    (run-python (python-shell-calculate-command) nil t)))
```

Environment: lsp,pyright,pipenv

Comment: It looks like this library https://github.com/muffinmad/emacs-django-commands/blob/master/django-commands.el may do what you wnat

Comment: @Rorschach Indeed that's the most promising help I've got so far. Yet I'm still looking how to `C-c C-c` (python-execute-file)

Comment: If you try this by hand: /home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-OfUvXXat/bin/python csv_import.py does it work? seems like the file's just not there.

Answer (score -1):

I don't use emacs but since this works

> This works as expected: python manage.py csv_import

What's the current directory of when you are inside emacs? Can you run `pwd` inside emacs to confirm?

Coz to me, this error only would occur, for example, if you are in another directory and you attempt to run this command, you'd get this error.

```
/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-OfUvXXat/bin/python: can't open file 'csv_import.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```